# Docker mysql - disable autocommit

Tags: mysql, docker, autocommit

i run docker image  mysql 5.7.41  with the command

`docker run --name mysql5r  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=aaa -p 3306:3306  -d mysql:5.7.41  --autocommit=FALSE`

But when i connect to mysql and run command

`SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name='autocommit';`

it return ON. How can i disable autocommit?

I also try

`docker run --name mysql55 -p3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=aa -d mysql:5.7.41 --skip-autocommit`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass as docker environment variable to disable autocommit like this,

`-e MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND="SET autocommit=0;"`

**Full Command:**

```
docker run --name mysql5r -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=aaa -e MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND="SET autocommit=0;" -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:5.7.41
```

Comment: I use -e MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND="SET autocommit=0;" but nothing changed

Comment: Try this full command: `docker run --name mysql5r -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=aaa -e MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND="SET autocommit=0;" -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:5.7.41
`

Comment: Nothing changed. Autocommit il always on. MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND is only for MySQL 8. I'm using mysql 5.7.41